# How to apply array_agg/array_to_json to a query with modified columns

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using `array_to_json` in combination with `array_agg` to format certain results in PostgreSQL as JSON.  This works fine for queries when I want to return the default value of a query (all columns, unmodified).  But I'm stumped how I could use `array_agg` to create a JSON object for a query where I want to modify some of the output.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_user ( 
   user_id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
   real_name text
);
CREATE TABLE temp_user_ip (
   user_id  integer,
   ip_address text
);
INSERT INTO temp_user (user_id, real_name) VALUES (1, 'Elise'),  (2, 'John'), (3, NULL);
INSERT INTO temp_user_ip (user_id, ip_address) VALUES (1, '10.0.0.4'),  (2, '10.0.0.7'), (3, '10.0.0.9');
```

The following query works fine:

```
# SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(temp_user)) as users from temp_user;
                                            users                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"user_id":1,"real_name":"Elise"},{"user_id":2,"real_name":"John"},{"user_id":3,"real_name":null}]
```

But let's say that I don't like the null value appearing for user 3.  I'd rather see the string "User logged in from $ip" instead.

I can do this:

```
# SELECT user_id, (CASE WHEN real_name IS NULL THEN (select 'User logged in from ' || ip_address FROM temp_user_ip WHERE user_id = temp_user.user_id) ELSE real_name END) as name from temp_user;
```

And I get the following results:

```
 user_id |             name             
---------+------------------------------
       1 | Elise
       2 | John
       3 | User logged in from 10.0.0.9
```

Which is great.  But I can't figure out how to manipulate this data into JSON format like the first example.

The desired output is:

```
[{"user_id":1,"name":"Elise"},{"user_id":2,"name":"John"},{"user_id":3,"name":"User logged in from 10.0.0.9"}]
```

This doesn't work:

```
# select array_to_json(array_agg ( (SELECT user_id, (CASE WHEN real_name IS NULL THEN (select 'User logged in from ' || ip_address FROM temp_user_ip WHERE user_id = temp_user.user_id) ELSE real_name END) as name from temp_user)));
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
```

I can't figure out any way to get the data into a format that `array_agg` accepts.  I even tried creating a custom type which matched the format of temp_user and trying to `array_agg` calls to the type constructor, which returned the same error.  The error doesn't make sense to me - if the subquery is aggregated, then it shouldn't matter if it returns more than one column.   Any advice?

Comment: Instead of CASE, you could just use COALESCE(exp, exp, n) as coalesce return the first no null value from the given argument list.

E.g.: COALESCE(real_name, 'user logged from xxxx')

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can separate the aggregate call from the subquery and use the [`row`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) constructor for generating the compound data:

```
SELECT 
    array_to_json(array_agg(row(t.*))) AS users 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT user_id, 
            CASE 
                WHEN real_name IS NULL 
                THEN (
                    SELECT 'User logged in from ' || ip_address 
                    FROM temp_user_ip 
                    WHERE user_id = temp_user.user_id
                ) ELSE real_name 
            END AS name 
        FROM temp_user
    ) t
;
```

You can also check this on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/eec4c/9).

Comment: I can confirm this works; I've just applied this method successfully to my real query.  Thanks!

Comment: The query can be simplified a little bit by replacing `array_agg(row(t.*))` by simply `array_agg(t)`. That way you also retain the column names from the subquery.

Answer (score 12):

PostgreSQL now has a function `json_agg` that can be used in lieu of `array_to_json(array_agg( ... ))` but actually behaves better in some cases. See "[Array_agg in postgres selectively quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262126/)" and the documentation: "[Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html)".

Here is the modified query:

```
SELECT 
    json_agg(row(t.*)) AS users 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT user_id, 
            CASE 
                WHEN real_name IS NULL 
                THEN (
                    SELECT 'User logged in from ' || ip_address 
                    FROM temp_user_ip 
                    WHERE user_id = temp_user.user_id
                ) ELSE real_name 
            END AS name 
        FROM temp_user
    ) t
;
```