# Array_agg in postgres selectively quotes

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a complex database with keys and values stored in different tables. It is useful for me to aggregate them when pulling out the values for the application:

```
   SELECT array_agg(key_name), array_agg(vals)
                    FROM (
                        SELECT
                            id,
                            key_name,
                            array_agg(value)::VARCHAR(255) AS vals
                        FROM factor_key_values
                        WHERE id=20
                        GROUP BY key_name, id
                    ) f;
```

This particular query, in my case gives the following invalid JSON:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
array_agg | {"comparison method","field score","field value"} 
array_agg | {"{\"text category\"}","{100,70,50,0,30}","{A,B,C,F,\"No Experience\"}"}
```

Notice that the array of varchars is only quoted if the string has a space. I have narrowed this down to the behaviour of `ARRAY_AGG`. For completeness here is an example:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE test (txt VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO test(txt) VALUES ('one'),('two'),('three'), ('four five');
SELECT array_agg(txt) FROM test;
```

The result will be:

```
{one,two,three,"four five"}
```

This is why my JSON is breaking. I can handle unquoted or quoted strings in the application code, but have a mix in nuts.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't you use `json_agg`?

```
select json_agg(txt) from test;
               json_agg               
--------------------------------------
 ["one", "two", "three", "four five"]
```

Comment: I tried this but the thing that its a rather large query that this is a subselect in, so if I json encode on an inner selected I end up double json encoded.

Comment: @FrankConry So go back to basics and show sample data and expected output.

Comment: I ended up having to refactor the entire query, but in the end, `json_agg` was the right choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is the inconsistent standard that PostgreSQL uses for formatting arrays. See "[Array Input and Output Syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-IO)" for more information.

Clodoaldo's answer is probably what you want, but as an alternative, you could also build your own result:

```
SELECT '{'||array_to_string(array_agg(txt::text), ',')||'}' FROM test;
```